# Is there a type-erased function wrapper in the Standard Library that matches std::thread's constructor semantics?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

I need to create a non-template class¹ that needs to hold a callable and its arguments, in order to invoke them at a later point.

Since this class is modelling an async execution, I'd like to give it API and semantics matching the ones of `std::thread` / `std::async`:

```
class Async {
public:
    template <typename Function, typename... Args >
    explicit Async(Function&& f, Args &&... args)
    {
         // perform a (decay) copy of the args,
         // store f and the copy somewhere
    }

    void call() 
    {
        // to be possibly called in a different thread;
        // call the function stored. no need to return the results
    }

private:
    // which data members?
};
```

The first thing that came into my mind is use a `std::function<void()>` as the only data member, and initialize it from a `std::bind` over the arguments.

However, this doesn't work: `std::function` and `std::bind` don't support move-only types, and `std::bind` simply does not work in terms of `std::invoke` (and it does a lot of extra magic, like recursively resolve bindings).

Am I missing some easy-to-reach solution available in the Standard Library to implement this, or should I deploy my own binder and type-erased function wrapper classes?

---

¹ Long story short: this class needs to inherit from a base class with virtual methods, so making this class a template class would cause the usual code bloat and clashes due to the duplication of virtual tables and virtual methods appearing everywhere.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<std::function<void()>>`

Comment: Use lambda instead of `std::bind`.

Comment: @Zereges: and save it into what?

Comment: @peppe Lambda is convertible to `std::function`.

Comment: But a `std::function` cannot store move-only lambdas. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class T> T&& wrap_pm(T&& t) { return std::forward<T>(t); }
template<class T, class U> 
auto wrap_pm(U T::* p) -> decltype(std::mem_fn(p)) { return std::mem_fn(p); }

class Async {
public:
    template <typename Function, typename... Args >
    explicit Async(Function&& f, Args &&... args)
      : fut(std::async(std::launch::deferred, 
                       [f=std::forward<Function>(f)](auto&&... args) mutable
                       {
                           wrap_pm(std::move(f))(decltype(args)(args)...); 
                       }, std::forward<Args>(args)...)) 
    { }
    void call() 
    {
        fut.get();
    }

private:
    std::future<void> fut;
};
```

I make no promises as to efficiency.

Comment: Nice one. Nitpicking, I think it requires `std::invoke` anyhow in there (e.g. if `f` is a PMF).

Comment: @peppe OK, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Technically `std::packaged_task<void()>` matches your requirements.  It is serious overkill, as it can interact with threading and can produce futures.

I have written a `task` that handles move-only invokation, it is pretty simple.  Getting the small buffer optimization right is harder.

```
class Async {
public:
  template <typename Function, typename... Args >
  explicit Async(Function&& f, Args &&... args) {
    task = [f=std::forward<Function>(f), args=std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]()mutable{
      std::apply(std::move(f), std::move(args));
    };
  }

  void call() {
    task();
    task={}; // don't call twice
  }

private:
  std::packaged_task<void()> task;
};
```

where I used C++17 std apply.  Just reimplement it, use google to find an implementaton.

Comment: Right, what I would really need is some "building block" of `packaged_task`. Is there anything in the Standard Library? (Also, what would I store in the `packaged_task`? A lambda, capturing both the function and the arguments (in a tuple, after decay_copy), whose body is just a call to `apply`?)

Comment: I'm settiling down on this solution for now (although it doesn't satisfy the original question). I've also added a call to `(void)task.get_future().get()` to make it rethrow exceptions, trying to mimic `std::thread`...